# How to have a gradient color across a single series chart in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, charts

In Excel I can insert a single series bar chart and select 'Vary colors by point' and get a chart where a primary color is shown as a gradient over the bars.

[image: Excel Chart]

When I attempt the same in Word I get different colors for each bar (as an aside this actually probably fits the features name better).

[image: Word Chart]

The problem is I can't find any way to format a chart in Word to look like the one in Excel. Is there some combination of settings that will accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When selecting colors, choose one of the "Monochromatic" alternatives under the "Change Colors" button in the Chart Tools -> Design Ribbon.

When activating "Vary colors by point" under the "Series options", it should all have the same color, but different shades.

The result:

[image: Word Chart]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and welcome to SuperUser. I inlined your image for easier viewing. Not sure how I missed that combination but it works now.